# Is there a simple way to track the reason by which comparison statement triggered?

Tags: javascript

For example

```
var reason = None;

if (a == 1 || b == 1) {
    x = True;
}

/*some code where x became True................*/
/*here I need to assign the "reason" variable with a or b value*/
```

If once x will equal True. How to find out, WHY x became True? Because a = 1 or because b = 1?
What is the reason? The reason is in "a" or is in "b"? I need to assing the "reason" variable by value a or b.

How to do this with minimum of code?(The simplest implementation)

Comment: Can you not make two if statements each one for a and b.

Comment: There is no `None` keyword in JavaScript, FYI. Also to answer your question: `var reason = 1;` Regardless of the "reason", the value of the variable you're interested in is `1` either way...

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a Python question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is trying to distinguish which part of a disjunction generated its truth value.

There are three reasons why `(a === 1 || b === 1)` might be true, they are (and this is exactly how you would test each), either:

```
a === 1
// one, or
b === 1
// the other, or
a === 1 && b === 1
// both
```

To put it in terms of the OP code...

```js
function why(a, b) {
  let x = false
  let reason = 'Neither a nor b are 1'

  if (a === 1 || b === 1) {
    x = true;
    if (a === 1 && b === 1) reason = 'Because both a and b are 1'
    else if (a === 1) reason = 'Because only a is 1'
    else reason = 'Because only b is 1'
  }
  return { x, reason }
}

console.log(why(0, 0))
console.log(why(0, 1))
console.log(why(1, 0))
console.log(why(1, 1))
```